# Python doesn't print in the order of the strings given

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

So lately I've been playing with threading and multiprocessing in python and i wanted to test this piece of code which prints the word 'Worker' in order...but the output is just not what you would normally expect.

And i found another peculiar difference that,if i run the code in IDLE(by pressing F5) i get the wrong output but if i run it in cmd,I get the correct output in the right order.

**Here's the code:**

```
import threading
import os

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print ('Worker: %s\n' % num)
    return

threads = []

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

os.system("pause")
```

**Here's the IDLE output:**

***Note:*** the order changes each time i run the code.

```
Worker: 0
Worker: 2
Worker: 1
Worker: 3
Worker: 4
```

**Here's the CMD output:**

***Note:***I'm getting some extra Linebreaks here.

```
Worker: 0

Worker: 1
Worker: 2


Worker: 3
Worker: 4


Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm confused as hell.I'm doing python for about 2 months.so yeah i'm a typical newbie.please explain me this mysterious phenomenon.And i'm using python 3.7 version

***EDIT:***
Ok,i got some clarity from the comments But even though the newline spaces vary, the order is executed perfectly everytime i run the code in CMD..do you think that each time the race condition favour the right order of 'Worker' while printing in CMD and not in IDLE?

here's another CMD output:

```
Worker: 0 
Worker: 1

Worker: 2

Worker: 3 


Worker: 4 

Press any key to continue . . .
```

*why are the conditions going haywire in IDLE and not in CMD?*

Comment: Threads are asynchronous. They don't necessarily run in the order they are started.

Comment: But everytime i run it in CMD the commands are synchronised..ie: they come in order

Comment: They also don't necessarily run *out* of order. Threads are not promised to run in any particular order; don't draw conclusions from any observations you may make.

Answer (score 3):

First, threads are asynchronous. They do not necessarily run in the order you start them, and when one thread is interrupted to allow another to run is up to the thread scheduler.

Second, `print(foo)` already prints a newline after it has printed each argument. That is, `print("foo")` and `print("foo\n", end='')` are equivalent.

Third, the fact that the CMD output isn't simply

```
Worker: 0

Worker: 1

Worker: 2

Worker: 3

Worker: 4
```

is indicative of race conditions. Each thread has a single `print` call, but the bytes written by each call are not written atomically to standard output. For example, the output you show could be explained by

1. Worker 0 has all its output written to standard output
2. Worker 1 has all but its final newline written to standard output
3. Worker 2 has all its output written to standard output
4. Worker 1 finally has its final newline written to standard output
5. Worker 3 has all but its final newline written to standard output
6. Worker 4 has all but its final newline written to standard output
7. Worker 3 finally has its final newline written to standard output
8. Worker 4 finally has its final newline written to standard output

Comment: Ok,i got some clarity.But even though the newline spaces vary.. the order is executed perfectly everytime i run the code in CMD..do you think that each time the race condition favour the right order of 'Worker' while printing in CMD?... ..here's another CMD output: ```Worker: 0
Worker: 1
\n
Worker: 2
\n
Worker: 3
\n
\n
Worker: 4
\n
Press any key to continue . . .
 ```(the newlines aren't projected while writing comments so i'm typing \n for them)...and why are the conditions going haywire in IDLE and not in CMD?